# not being able to install kdump non-interactively on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I am trying to enable kdump through a script in the following way

```
echo "kexec-tools kexec-tools/load_kexec boolean false" | sudo debconf-set-selections
update /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt install linux-crashdump -fy --fix-missing
```

It still asks the question

```
If you choose this option, a system reboot will trigger a restart into a kernel loaded by kexec instead of going through the full system boot loader process. Should kexec-tools handle reboots (sysvinit only)?
```

Could anyone please let me know some way to do this non-interactively?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your **`init`** system as to whether this answer actually matters:

If your system uses, for example, **`systemd`** (or any *non*-**`sysvinit`** system), answering this question either way apparently has no impact. ([Source](https://www.theo-andreou.org/?tag=linux-en-2))

Since 2015, `systemd` is used by most of the major Linux distributions, (e.g. Ubuntu, Red Hat ...), but if your system uses `sysvinit`, answer the question as you see fit.